# Add metrics to profile page to measure the users influence

Tags: feature-request

In addition to the reputation score there could be additional metrics on a users profile page measuring the influence of the user. The influence of a user can be measured with bibliometric measures, such as the [h-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index). There is already [an implementation for the h-index](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45195/what-is-my-h-index) on StackExchange DataExplorer. For StackExchange related sites, I find the defininition used in the implementation useful:

> Your h-index is the highest number n, such that you have at least n questions/answers, all of which have at least n score [upvotes].

Comment: But how is this better/different than reputation? All this would be doing is put more value on quantity (number of posts) than perceived quality (number of upvotes).

Comment: Neither quantity nor quality by itself can raise the h-index. Only a combination of both can raise the h-index. Users with a high h-index have more influential answers/questions and provide consistent value to many other users. As it is possible to achieve a high reputation with a single question or answer, the reputation is not a good measure for that.

Comment: What would be the purpose of your suggestion? What use would it be?

Comment: OK, I see what you're getting at. Still, the index would favour users with a track record of mediocre answers over one with fewer, more upvoted ones. It might make more sense to limit the impact that a single contribution  has on the index - effectively, a per-post reputation cap. (That has been suggested an rejected multiple times in the past though; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again and its answers)

Comment: Google Scholar shows H-index; it is a well-established measure. Why not here too, indeed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The H-index is a standard now in measuring quality of academic research, exactly because it does not favor a track record of many mediocre papers, nor does it favor a track record of a small number of good papers.  To get a high H-index, one must consistently produce high quality research.  On SO the fastest way to get lots of reputation is to answer mediocre questions that lots of others could answer - just answering first rather than demonstrating higher quality than others.  To get a high H-index, one needs to focus on harder questions that apply to many people.

Comment: [Here are a few SEDE queries for generating h-index rankings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369548/2751851).