# Generating h-index rankings with SEDE

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer

In academia, the [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) for an author is *h* if *h* is the largest number for which there are at least *h* papers cited at least *h* times. There has been interest in devising an h-index analogue for Stack Overflow answer authors (cf. [*Add metrics to profile page to measure the users influence*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277706/2751851) and [*Stack Overflow h-index metric?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368467/2751851)). While there is [a SEDE query that calculates an h-index for a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45195/what-is-my-h-index), it would be nice to have an h-index ranking as well, in order to have a better idea of to which extent it highlights contributions differently from the usual metrics (e.g. reputation and tag scores).

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two ways of defining a h-index analogue for Stack Overflow. One of them substitutes answer scores for citation counts.

- [Here is a query for a score-based h-index ranking](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862452/h-index-based-on-answer-scores-ranking). The restriction to posts with at least 10 score is there primarily to avoid resource exhaustion while running the query. Guess who is the leader?
- [A version of the ranking for specific tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862455/h-index-based-on-answer-scores-ranking-per-tag). It also includes the highest relevant tag badge attained by the users, which neatly highlights significant contributors to a tag that still don't have gold or silver badges.

An alternative h-index, [as suggested by Mike McCaughan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368467/stack-overflow-h-index-metric?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment593774_368467), uses the number of duplicates that have the parent question as target instead of the answer score. That is a less straightforward metric, but it arguably provides a closer match to the academia h-index.

- [A duplicate-based ranking](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862466/h-index-based-on-duplicates-ranking), and [its adaptation to specific tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862817/h-index-based-on-duplicates-ranking-per-tag) (which also includes tag badges).
- While high duplicate-based h-index values are generally harder to reach than score-based ones, the duplicate-based index is, in a way, easier to game -- in particular, by posting a lot of late answers to popular duplicate targets. One way of countering this effect is making the index only count accepted answers. [Here is this more stringent version of the ranking](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862503/h-index-based-on-duplicates-ranking-accepted-only), as well as [its tag-specific counterpart](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862512/h-index-based-on-duplicates-ranking-per-tag-accepted-only).